# Distinct characters across multiple strings

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get a distinct list of characters (case sensitive) across all strings in a list.

I have a list containing 3 strings:

```
"AABbDDCCRRFF"
"JOJaCK"
"BILLY"
```

The Output should be like (order of the characters is not important):

```
ABDCRFJOKaILYb
```

I know the below is wrong but can't work it out:

```
            distChars = (from string row in valuesList[c]
                         select row.Distinct()
                         ).Distinct().ToString();
```

Does anyone know how to return the distinct characters from across each string. If this can't be done in LINQ then i'm open to alternatives.
Thanks!

Update:
wow, great answers, so fast!  What would be the approach to get the characters ordered alphabetically or by frequency of occurence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you’re first selecting the distinct characters from *within* each row, then selecting the distinct *sequences* of characters, and finally calling `ToString` on an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I would suggest that you first select *all* characters from all your rows, apply the `Distinct` filter on the combined sequence, and finally call `string.Concat` to concatenate the resultant sequence of characters:

```
var distChars = string.Concat(
    (
        from row in valuesList[c]
        from c in row
        select c
    ).Distinct());
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do in this way:

```
string[] values = new []{"AABbDDCCRRFF","JOJaCK","BILLY"};

var uniqueChars = new string(values.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToArray());
```

**EDIT :**

as suggested by @Douglas, it could be slightly more efficient using `string.Concat()` instead of `new string()`, i.e. :

```
var uniqueChars = string.Concat(values.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct());
```

Comment: +1 for conciseness. However, I assume that `string.Concat(sequence)` would be more efficient than `new string(sequence.ToArray())` since it avoids the array initialization.

Comment: @Douglas: Yes, probably it would be slightly more efficient, because it avoids the creation of a throw-away array. Even if I doubt one can notice the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
var valuesList = new List<string> {"AABbDDCCRRFF", "JOJaCK", "BILLY"};

var distChars = string.Join("", (from str in valuesList  // Select all strings.
                                 from ch in str          // Select all chars.
                                 select ch).Distinct()); // Get distinct chars.
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to have distinct chars not strings.

```
var strings = new string[] { "AABbDDCCRRFF", "JOJaCK", "BILLY" };
var q = (from str in strings
         from c in str
         select c).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you have a collection of collections. Try joining the strings prior to selecting distinct characters.